# Flutter | auto_size_text inside of Expanded FittedBox

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, flutter-packages

### *Disclaimer:*

I am very new to flutter, this is my first solo project that I am creating. All other projects have only been very short tutorials. The problem I am having (described below) may seem like a very easy fix, but as I am new please do explain it in detail as best you can, being able to visualize what you are saying also helps (through code, diagrams etc). Thank you.

## Problem:

Unable to get `auto_size_text` `maxLines` to work correctly. On top of this, unable to get `MaxFontSize` working.

### Further Explanation

I am using the [auto_size_text package](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text), setup with the `pubspec.yaml` dependency: `auto_size_text: ^2.1.0` and `import: 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart'`. I also changed my `pubspec.yaml` environment from `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` to `sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"` to allow non null safe packages to work - as per direction of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6WqqFGP_Ck).

I am creating a container inside of my app, inside of this container is a Column widget, inside the Column widget are several rows. One of these rows is intended as a title. The code for it is below:

```
Row( // Row is inside of a Column which is inside of a Container
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(width: 55), // Used to create padding either side of text
                  Expanded(
                    child: FittedBox(
                        child: AutoSizeText(
                          '70 | Brighton  - Abbotsford and Green Island', // Header Example
                          maxLines: 2, // Cannot get this to work, always remains one line
                          maxFontSize: 20, // Does not work, always resizes to max font in order to fill whole FittedBox
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20, // Unsure if I need this, adding or removing seems to have to effect.
                            color: color.AppColor.textMain.withOpacity(0.8), 
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 55), // Used to create padding either side of text
                ],
              ),
```

With this code I get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7pny.png) - Note that the blue line is another row above the title but still inside of the same Column widget.

### Desired Result:

The font is far too small, so I want it to be split among two lines. I am designing this container to be reused and I will later change it so the text is imported from a CSV file so name lengths will be varied. They all need to be readable, and while it's fine for smaller titles ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsLEY.png)), larger ones need to have a bigger font while still fitting inside the same boundaries, so two lines is required. As also mentioned, I am unable to get the `maxFontSize` working, resulting in shorter titles having too large of a font.

### Attempted Solutions:

I have tired using a null safe version of `auto_size_text` but was unable to get it working (as it's a prerelease I assume it isn't functioning properly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I solved my own problem almost accidently while playing around with the code I posted in the original question.

### Solution:

Although not the most convenient, the solution is to replace the `Expanded` widget and `FittedBox` to a `SizedBox`. Below is the adjusted code including comments about changes made.

```
               Row( // Row is inside of a Column which is inside of a Container
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(width: 55), // Used to create padding either side of text
                  SizedBox( // Changed the Expanded and FittedBox to a sized box with a width of 280, source container has a width of 390, so text is allowed a width of 280 once you subtract the width 55 SizedBox's either side
                    width: 280,
                      child: AutoSizeText(
                        '70 | Brighton  - Abbotsford and Green Island', // Header Example
                        maxLines: 2, // Cannot get this to work, always remains one line
                        maxFontSize: 20, // Does not work, always resizes to max font in order to fill whole FittedBox
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20, // Unsure if I need this, adding or removing seems to have to effect.
                          color: color.AppColor.textMain.withOpacity(0.8),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 55), // Used to create padding either side of text
                ],
              ),
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution without using `auto_size_text` package

```
SizedBox(
    child: TextField(
        controller: _yourController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        ),
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        maxLines: null,
    ),
),
```

`keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline` makes `TextField` can be resized automatically and move to new line if it reach max width, and

`maxLines: null` makes your text can be written with many lines, and then

`decoration` here i use to remove `TextField` box border

Comment: This isn't quite what I want, the title isn't going to be a user input. The title will come from a CSV file that I have already loaded into the app (through my assets folder). I have done it this way as I will likely need to quickly duplicate my container with another new title if the CSV is ever updated. I will be converting the code I posted into a widget so this is achievable. The purpose of it currently is only for me to figure out how to make it so all the titles fit and are readable, meaning some will have to take up two lines.